# How to Parse a code file?

Tags: php, class, parsing, methods

Writing from phone so sorry if not typed well. I want to Parse a file in php but it's a php file. I want to extract thinks such as namespace functions and classes. How is that best done? 
I am reading in the php file like a text file and trying to understand where things start and finish.

I tried doing this all at the same time but because too confusing to apply parse.
So now I have different objects parsing. Namespace, classes, method. 
But it's have to keep track what is where and what is inside what.

Keep in mind the different ways a namespace can be written in php. How would one do this. Parse the file and understand the classes and methods that are in it. This is not limited to php it will need to extend to other languages too.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) is a php parser written in php. I think this tool will fill your needs.

Comment: This is a good start but I don't want it linked to one language. I also didn't want to have to load the entire file to do this. I know how to do it with the entire file in memory was just hoping to avoid that.

Comment: It is a very difficult problem. Each language has its own syntax. Maybe you can do something for languages with "similar" syntax, but I just can't imagine a way of parsing haskell, ruby, scala programs with the same tool. Good luck with that.

Comment: I will be using different classes for each language. But all will implement the same interface to allow for such things.

Comment: You haven't stated that you want to parse "any" langugage.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [tokenizer](http://de3.php.net/tokenizer) extension. It basically offers you one function `token_get_all()` with the source code as a string (`file_get_contents()` first), and returns an array with all the code parsed into PHP internal atoms, which is way easier to parse than fiddling with the source yourself.